Cartoon movie from 80's, possibly Russian fairytale
I'm trying to find a movie that I watched once as a teenager, so in the 80's. It was cartoon, not live-action, and I believe the story was a Russian fairytale.
The protagonist was a boy who was sent to be an apprentice to a miller, who turned out to be a wizard/magician/evil man with magic. There were lots of boys living there, and I think they were all taught magic. But when they got to be a certain age they would disappear.
At the end, the protagonist and some/all the other boys defeated the evil magician.
My memory of the film is that the colouring was very bright, lots of primary colours, and the characters were rather stylized than realistically drawn. I'd really like to find the film again, or at least get a hint of which fairytale or story it was based on, if any.

Most probably it's Krabat – The Sorcerer's Apprentice, 1978 Czechoslovak adaptation of a German book.

Krabat, a beggar boy in early 18th century Lusatia, is lured to become
  an apprentice to an evil, one-eyed sorcerer. Together with a number of
  other boys, he works at the sorcerer's mill under slave-like
  conditions while learning black magic, such as guising himself as a
  raven and other animals. Every Christmas one of the boys has to face
  the master in a magical duel of life and death, where the boy never
  stands a chance because the master is the only person who is allowed
  to use his secret grimoire: The Koraktor, or the Force of Hell.
After witnessing his friends one after one being helplessly
  slaughtered by the master every Christmas, Krabat starts to sneak up
  at night to study the forbidden book. On the last page of the book,
  Krabat finds a phrase saying: "Love is stronger than any spell." This
  is used when he ultimately has to defeat his master for the sake of
  love.


That's the one, thank you so much!
